# Why does an error occur when installing OpenCV for Qt using CMake?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

In CMake, I'm trying to generate an assembly for OpenCV. OS is Windows 10. The configuration was successful, but when I click "Generate", the following error appears:

```
CMake Error in modules/highgui/CMakeLists.txt:
No known features for CXX compiler

""

version .
```

Do I need to edit `CMakeLists.txt` or is it related to the need to add some directory in the Path?

The content of CMakeList.txt : 
https://pastebin.com/T1JKfti3

Comment: What have you in the `CMakeLists.txt`? Try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55047842/edit) your post by adding the `CMakeLists.txt` content.

Comment: @SenDjasni, added a link to content of this file.